# How to remove recurring elements in a list

Tags: python-3.x

How to remove duplicate elements from a list , 
Example :`my_list =[2,5,7,9,10,4,2,9]`
I want to display only the unique elements and not the recurring elements ..

Comment: Use a set. `list(set(my_list))`

Comment: Thanks  bro ✌

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing duplicates in lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7961363/removing-duplicates-in-lists)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

like this:

```
list1 = [2,5,7,9,10,4,2,9]
list2 = list(dict.fromkeys(list1))
print(list2)
```

Comment: `list(set(list1))` is more straightforward